# increment MySql column in with ActiveRecord Yii framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm going to increment one of my database table column by one unit in yii framework.I want to use activeRecords and updateByAll() function instead of load the model and call save()  method.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify at what point you want to increment the column?

Why not just extend the ActiveRecord-class and increment the column where it needs incrementing and then just call the parent implementation. For example:

```
class ActiveRecord extends CActiveRecord {
    public updateAll($attributes, $condition='', $params=array()) {
        $this->incCol++;
        parent::updateAll($attributes, $condition, $params);
    }
}
```